# Where should I put base.html in django project?

Tags: django

What is the correct way to put the base.html file in django so that other apps can modify it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "modify?" Render? Or actually edit the file?

Comment: I see that you are new on Stackoverflow. If this answer was helpful to you and solved your problem you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

You can place it anywhere you want in your templates directory. I suggest at the root of your templates directory.

```
project/
    app-1/
    ...
    app-n/
    templates/
        base.html
```

Your templates directory should be listed under the TEMPLATES setting in the `settings.py`.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            '/path/to/project/templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```